# Efficiently filling NumPy array using lists of indices

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, vectorization, joblib

I know how to execute a parallel loop in `joblib` that returns a list as result.

However, is it possible to fill a predefined `numpy` matrix in parallel?

Imagine the following minimal example matrix and data:

```
column_data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'x']
data = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['d', 'c'],
        ['e', 'f', 'd', 'x']]
x = np.zeros((len(data), len(column_data))
```

Note that `column_data` is sorted and unique. `data` is a list of lists, not a rectangular matrix.

The loop:

```
for row in range(len(data)):
    for column in data[row]:
        x[row][column_data.index(column)] = 1
```

It is possible to parallellise this loop? Filling in a `70,000 x 10,000` matrix is quite slow without parallellisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an *almost*  vectorized approach -

```
lens = [len(item) for item in data]    
A = np.concatenate((column_data,np.concatenate(data)))
_,idx = np.unique(A,return_inverse=True)

R = np.repeat(np.arange(len(lens)),lens)
C = idx[len(column_data):]

out = np.zeros((len(data), len(column_data)))    
out[R,C] = 1
```

Here's another -

```
lens = [len(item) for item in data]
R = np.repeat(np.arange(len(lens)),lens)
C = np.searchsorted(column_data,np.concatenate(data))

out = np.zeros((len(data), len(column_data)))
out[R,C] = 1
```

Comment: I'm so sorry to have caused this ambiguation. I improved my question. `data` is not a square matrix but rather a list of lists. `column_data` is sorted and unique.

Comment: I finally understood your older code and see you edited it to only 4 lines :). Let me see if I can figure out what this is doing. Awesome techniques btw, it's crazy fast.

Comment: @Tim Added another one, check it out.

Comment: np.uniques makes intuitively more sense to me so I'll stick with that one. Thank you for providing more insight into the numpy vectorization!

Comment: @Tim No worries! The second approach that uses `np.searchsorted`might be your next stop, if you are looking for vectorization in  NumPy, as that function is crazy fast!

Comment: @Tim Also, curious on what kind of speedups you are getting with these approaches over your loopy approach, if you happen to run some benchmarks?

Comment: The speed up is quite significant. For a matrix of `39774 x 6461` the original code took `42.27s` and your code took `0.99s` :).

Comment: @Tim Terrific really! Thanks for getting those numbers!